# Changing Multiple Host Names on Domain using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Trying to create a PowerShell script to change the name of about 300 machines to match one naming scheme. I have figured out a way to do this through PS but only one-by-one and that's just not going to cut it.

Current Process:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_Bios -ComputerName 'hostname' | Select-Object SerialNumber
```

Followed by: (Using the last 5 of the serial)

```
RenameComputer -ComputerName "curretHostName" -NewName "TEST-(last 5)" -DomainCredential xxxxx
```

Thought process is creating an array using:

```
$ComputerNames += Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "*"' | FT Name -A
```

Then using a ForEach loop on each name in the $ComputerNames array. But this is where I am stuck. I was trying to start small and just get the return of the SerialNumbers and go from there. This is my current ISE that's not working.

```
$ComputerNames += Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "testComputerName"' | FT Name -A
ForEach ($name in $ComputerNames)
    {
       Get-WMIObject Win32_Bios -ComputerName '*' | Select-Object SerialNumber
       }
```

This is the first big thing I have done with PS btw so this has been a lot to take in!

Any advice is greatly appreciated. This task was handed to me this morning so it’s fresh. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what version of Powershell you're using; I'm going to assume that you're using 5.1, and any links to Powershell cmdlets that I give you will be to that version.

Note: I'm going to walk though this step-by-step. ***DON'T USE ANY CODE EXCEPT AT THE END. I WILL BE STARTING WITH YOUR CODE AND PROGRESSIVELY REFINING IT.***

You've actually got most of what you need already; the trick is now putting it together. This is where the Powershell pipeline comes into play; what you want to do is grab a whole bunch of objects, and then use your process above for each of them.

"...for each...". That's an interesting phrase. Interesting enough that Microsoft actually has it as a pipeline cmdlet in Powershell. This cmdlet is called [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-5.1).

So, you want to get a bunch of computers out of ActiveDirectory, and then FOR EACH of them, you want to

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_Bios -ComputerName 'hostname' | Select-Object SerialNumber
Rename-Computer -ComputerName "curretHostName" -NewName "TEST-(last 5)" -DomainCredential xxxxx
```

That's

```
ForEach-Object {
    Get-WMIObject Win32_Bios -ComputerName 'hostname' | Select-Object SerialNumber
    Rename-Computer -ComputerName "curretHostName" -NewName "TEST-(last 5)" -DomainCredential xxxxx
}
```

You already know how to get your computers from ActiveDirectory:

```
Get-ADComputer
```

You don't need your `-Filter`, because you're asking for all of them (`'Name -like "*"'`), so just the cmdlet is enough. If you were to assign it to a variable, it would already be an array, but we're going to use the pipeline instead.

So now you want to hand those computers off to the `ForEach-Object` block:

```
Get-ADComputer | ForEach-Object {
    Get-WMIObject Win32_Bios -ComputerName 'hostname' | Select-Object SerialNumber
    Rename-Computer -ComputerName "curretHostName" -NewName "TEST-(last 5)" -DomainCredential xxxxx
}
```

There's a special variable when you're using the Powershell pipeline. `$_` means *the current object being passed through the pipeline*. In this case, it's one of the objects returned by `Get-ADComputer`. It will have all of the members that an `ADComputer` object will have, so the name of the computer will be `$_.Name`. We can use that...

```
Get-ADComputer | ForEach-Object {
    Get-WMIObject Win32_Bios -ComputerName $_.Name | Select-Object SerialNumber
    Rename-Computer -ComputerName $_.Name -NewName "TEST-(last 5)" -DomainCredential xxxxx
}
```

Now, there's a trick you can use in Powershell. If you enclose a statement in parentheses `()`, you can assign the result of that statement to a variable. In this case, if we enclose the line starting with `Get-WMIObject` in parentheses, and assign it to the variable `$SN`, we'll have the serial number all ready to play with:

```
Get-ADComputer | ForEach-Object {
    $SN = (Get-WMIObject Win32_Bios -ComputerName $_.Name | Select-Object SerialNumber)
    Rename-Computer -ComputerName $_.Name -NewName "TEST-(last 5)" -DomainCredential xxxxx
}
```

Now, you want to take that serial number, chop off all but the last five characters, and prefix it with (in your example) "TEST-". That's not difficult, though there is a little bit of strangeness involved:

```
$Last5 = $SN[-5..-1] -join ""
$NewName = "TEST-$Last5"
```

Powershell allows you to use negative subscripts to work from the right end of a string. Unfortunately, this gives you an array of characters rather than a string, so we join them into a string with `-join ""`. The `""` is a null "separator"; in other words, join the characters together with nothing between them. If a variable is embedded by name in a string enclosed with double-quotes ("), its value will be substituted - so if `$Last5` contained `12345`, we'd end up with `$NewName` being `TEST-12345`.

Let's add that to the `ForEach-Object` block:

```
Get-ADComputer | ForEach-Object {
    $SN = (Get-WMIObject Win32_Bios -ComputerName $_.Name | Select-Object SerialNumber)
    $Last5 = $SN[-5..-1] -join ""
    $NewName = "TEST-$Last5"
    Rename-Computer -ComputerName $_.Name -NewName $NewName -DomainCredential xxxxx
}
```

...and now all you have to do is add your domain credential information and you'll be good to go.

> *Well, no. It turns out that I mistyped something up there. In order to get a string that contains the serial number, instead of an object with one member called "SerialNumber" which in turn contains the serial number, the line beginning with `$SN =` needs to read*

```
$SN = (Get-WMIObject Win32_Bios -ComputerName $_.Name | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SerialNumber)
```

> *That will give you what you (I) expected.*

***DO A "DESK CHECK" OF THE CODE FIRST, AND MAYBE EVEN TEST IT BY MANUALLY EXECUTING EACH STEP USING A KNOWN COMPUTER.*** You need to be sure that what you're doing is what you want to do, and that I'm not some sort of nasty scum that's giving you code that will be deliberately and maliciously destructive. (I'm not, but you don't know that.)

I strongly suggest you get yourself some decent books on Powershell, and bookmark [SS64 on Powershell](https://ss64.com/ps/) as a reference. Also, if you use a Powershell cmdlet as the search term to any of the major search engines, one of the first hits will be that cmdlet's page at [Microsoft Docs on Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/), which will give you very complete information.

Comment: Gohlee. I will take a look through this in detail tomorrow when I get to work and let you know if I have any questions. This is awesome and I really appreciate!

Comment: This is amazing and I appreciate you taking the time to explain it all. Looking over it with my small PowerShell knowledge it 110% makes sense. Just wasn't sure how to make it all talk. I will try it manually with a few machines and then probably  adjust my Get-ADComputer to get one OU at a time, have about 15 different areas I have to this to.  Thanks so much Jeff, I will reach out if I have any questions along the way but I think my googling paired with this guide can get me exactly what I need.

Comment: Running the "$Last5" portion returns a blank output. So a name is returning "Test-" and that's it. Trying to play around with arrays and such but have had no luck. Assigning "$SN" works and I can call on that.

Comment: Make sure that your SN doesn't have trailing blanks! It doesn't on the computer I tested that SN manipulation on, but I can imagine computers that might... If yours does, you might want to try `$Last5 = $SN.Trim()[-5..-1] -join ""`.

Comment: See my edit to the code above - with the grey bar, and the italics.